# C# query with filter condition

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have a list of TransportType to filter from
the application should compare the user selection with this list then return only what he selected which should be in the defined list

```
 private static readonly string[] ValidTransportType = new string[]
    {
        "Cars", 
        "Airplans", 
        "Audi",
        "BMW", 
        "Airbus A333", 
        "Boing 747",
    };

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetSelectedTypes(IEnumerable<string> userSelection )
    {
        var list = (from transport in ValidTransportType
                    where userSelection.Contains(transport)
                    select transport).ToList();

        return list;
    }
```

for example: if user selected "Car", "Porsche" then the result will be only "Car" because porsche was not defined.

My question is, how can i modify the Linq query to perform the following:
If user selected "Cars", "Audi", "BMW" the query returns Cars because cars includes BMW and AUDI, if the user Selects "Audi" and "BMW" then the application will return "Audi" and "BMW" but not "cars" because it was not selected , if user selected "BMW", "AUDI", "Airplanes", "Boing 747" then the application should return list of "BMW", "Audi", "Airplanes" But not "Boing 747" becuase Airplanes includes "Boing 747"

Any Idea?

> Edit:

Please notice that the type and type to compare are unkown before runtime, both are coming from exteranl files, example: in my example i put cars, but it can be animal, Technology, person ... etc, that's why i cannot predict the type and create classes upfront.

Comment: In your current form you don't have relation between Cars -> Audi, BMW. Think about a base class `Cars` with sub classes BMW, Audi, or a dictionary structure with BMW and Audi having value as Car, something like that.

Comment: @Habib thanks for your reply, the problem is the input is from external csv file, and list to compare is also from external file. it can be cars, animals whatever, but always there is an abstract type which is the first word of each line in the file (Cars, Airplanes, Animals ... etc)

Comment: then I would suggest to have `Dictionary<string,string>` with each item as key and value as their type. Later you can access them through type, but you have to have a relationship in your objects to get the relevant data.

Comment: Thanks @Habib, Actually this is what i'm doing, i'm using a Dictionary <string,List<string>> where List<string> is the input that i want to filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually easier without a linq query, but with a plain old `foreach` loop.

First, let's create a dictionary to group `BMW` and `Audi` into a `Cars` group etc.:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
string[] items = {"Cars,BMW", "Cars,Audi", "Animals,Dog"};
foreach (var item in items)
{
    // TODO: use better variable names
    // you probably use a csv parser for this
    var s = item.Split(',');

    // fill the dictionary. 
    if (!d.ContainsKey(s[0]))
        d[s[0]] = new List<string>();
    d[s[0]].Add(s[1]);
}
```

Then, the implementation of `GetSelectedTypes` could look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetSelectedTypes(Dictionary<string, List<string>> validTypes, IEnumerable<string> userSelection )
{
    foreach (var kvp in validTypes)
        // if the key is in userSelection, only return the key, but no items
        if (userSelection.Contains(kvp.Key))
            yield return kvp.Key;
        // if not, only return valid items
        else 
            foreach (var item in kvp.Value)
                if (userSelection.Contains(item))
                    yield return item;
}
```

simple test:

```
string[] userSelection = {"Cars", "Audi", "Dog"};
// will be [Cars, Dog], because Cars include Audi
GetSelectedTypes(d, userSelection);

string[] userSelection2 = {"BMW", "Audi", "Dog", "Animals"};
// will be [BMW, Audi, Animals] because Animals include Dog
GetSelectedTypes(d, userSelection2);
```